# Swift Run Code Right After Singleton Initialization

Tags: ios, swift

I have some Swift code that I want to run right after my singleton gets initialized. The reason this code needs to run after my singleton is initialized is because the code relies on that singleton existing.

I have the following example code of what I'm aiming to do. But it looks like this code isn't working because the `refreshData` is trying to access the singleton before it's fully been created.

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
    static let shared: MyObject = MyObject()

    let otherManager: OtherStuff = OtherStuff()

    var number: Int = 1

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        print("Setup code goes here")
        otherManager.refreshData()
    }
}

class OtherStuff {
    func refreshData() {
        MyObject.shared.number += 1
        print(MyObject.shared.number)
    }
}
```

On [repl.it](https://repl.it) it prints `Setup code goes here` and just kinda hangs forever. The example I'm working with is a lot more complicated, but I believe this small example accurately reproduces the issue I'm having.

How can I fix this so that I wait for the singleton to be setup and everything before running that code?

Comment: @Mocha When I run `p MyObject.shared` it prints `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`

Comment: Wouldn’t this be an infinite loop? If you execute `let myObj = MyObject.shared`, it’s going to call your init method. `init()` doesn’t return until `setup()` returns, which relies on `OtherStuff.refreshData()`. Because `MyObject.shared` hasn’t been initialized when `refreshData()` references it, `init()` is called again, and so on. Not sure what you’re working towards here, but this type of circular dependency and tight coupling is good to avoid.

Comment: @Drew Yeah makes sense. So is there a way to only call `setup` after `myObj` has been fully initialized and setup?

Comment: E.Coms answer is probably the best bet to get you going. There’s also Swift’s `defer` statement which will execute a block after a method returns. But more generally I’d suggest you examine whether you need these two objects to depend on each other in this way, and design a looser coupling if possible. You’ll probably find that much more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: *Actually*, don't use `defer`. I was mis-remembering how that works. `defer` executes before current scope exits and cannot cause a change of scope within, so would be inappropriate here. Sorry, got turned around for a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `setup`, and thus sending your `refreshData` message to the `otherManager`, before `init` has a chance to return, so there is no MyObject yet. This is solved by stepping out of the runloop to the next runloop:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.setup() }
}
```

Comment: This actually looks like a super clean solution. This will ensure that `shared` is always available before calling `setup`? It's not like there is a potential for a race condition here or anything?

Comment: Well, if you're worried that someone else might call `setup`, make it private (or move its content directly into those curly braces). Otherwise I don't see where the race is; there is only one main thread and it is serial.

Comment: This is a bit misleading, `async` is `later` and does not guarantee `setup` before the object is used. If instance of `MyObject` is used after init, in a way that requires the instance to have been `setup`, this solution will fail as setup block could be preceded by several lines of code that follow `init`. 
I'll add a playground test further proving this in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example not to call infinite shared object, but use the existing singleton to do the rest work.

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
static let shared: MyObject = MyObject()

let otherManager: OtherStuff = OtherStuff()

var number: Int = 1

override init() {
    super.init()
   setup()
}

func setup() {
    print("Setup code goes here")
    otherManager.refreshData(self)
}
}

class OtherStuff {
  func refreshData(_ myObject: MyObject) {
    myObject.number += 1
    print(myObject.number)
 }
}
```

Comment: I really want to avoid this if at all possible. Because of how my project is setup this would just add a lot of elements that I think would create a lot of confusion and complexity. Not saying I won't end up going with this solution. But I'd love to see other potential solutions since I'm really looking for something cleaner than this.

Comment: Remove setup() from init(), and call   MyObject.shared.setup() first to guarantee the singleton existing. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Swifty way if you can change `OtherManager`'s refresh function signature, i.e. `func refreshData()` to `func refreshData(for: MyObject)`:

```
static let shared: MyObject = {
    let object = MyObject()
    otherManager.refreshData(for: object)
    return object
}()
```

Or, although a bit bulky (and Objective C style), I would use a private `shared` instance and call `setup` in its property observer.

```
static var shared: MyObject {
    get {
        if _shared == nil {
            _shared = MyObject()
        }
        return _shared
    }
}

private static var _shared: MyObject! = nil {
    didSet {
        shared.setup()
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Why `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.setup() }` is not the right solution:

```
class Test: NSObject {

    var value: Int!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setup()
        }
    }

    func setup() {
        value = 1
    }
}

let test = Test()

// error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION...
let value: Int = test.value
```

The last line of code `let value: Int = test.value` was called before the object had a chance to call setup, unsurprisingly as it was `async` call.